# Does passing dataframe to a function or assigning a new variable to a dataframe cause data copy?

Tags: apache-spark

For example

```
  def transform(myDF: DataFrame) (implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {

     // do something

  }


  val myDf1 =  spark.read.format("avro").load("hdfs://myavrofile")
  val myDf2 = transform(myDf1)
```

Is the above code inefficient? Because first we have to copy over the data to function and reassign the data to a new dataframe?

Or spark internally optimize such that dataframe is just a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Plus to Hamza's answer, it's a good habit to cache the parent dataframe, if you want to create a branch from it (for example `val df1 = transform1(df); val df2 = transform2(df)`). Because spark creates a lineage and if you don't cache the parent dataframe, in each action, calculations are done from the beginning. So:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object DataFrameOptimization {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("DataFrameOptimization")
      .getOrCreate()

    val myDf1 = spark.read.format("avro").load("hdfs://myavrofile").cahce()
    val myDf2 = transform(myDf1, 10)
    val myDf3 = transform(myDf1, 20)

    // Perform some action on myDf2 to trigger the execution
    myDf2.show()
    myDf3.show()
  }

  def transform(myDF: DataFrame, n: Int)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    // Perform some transformation on the DataFrame
    // For example, let's filter the rows based on a condition
    myDF.filter(s"column_name >= $n")
  }
}
```

You can check the effect of cache, by checking `explain("formatted")` method of each transformed dataframes. Finally, if you're dataset is heavy, you can change the `StorageLevel` by calling `persist` instead of `cache`.